# Zebra non-RFID printer: sending RFID command consequence?

Tags: rfid, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I'm working in an RFID pilot-project that requires me to edit a ZPL file to include RFID commands to send to a RFID printer. ("^RF"  to encode an RFID tag in ZPL langage)

My question is, what happens if you send that same RFID command to a non-RFID printer?

Is the command going to mess with the print result, or will that command be ignored ?

I have no way for now of getting hands on a non-RFID printer from Zebra, hence my question.

I hope I'm not being off the chart!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who will end up with that same question, I've been answered by contacting Zebra support directly. Non-RFID printers will just ignore the RFID commands with no impact on the printing results.